# Convert a "pygame" into .exe using py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I created a game using pygame (python2.7) and tried to convert it using py2exe.

These are the modules I used:
pygame,Tkinter,random
here's my "setup.py":

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(options={
            "py2exe":{
                "includes": ["Tkinter","pygame","random"]

            }
    }
)
```

when I try to run the .exe file I get this Error:

```
NotImplementedError: font module not avaible
(ImportError: DLL load failed: module couldn't be found
```

What do I have to change?

Comment: The game is running without any errors while its not converted

Answer (score 1):

There's two things to check here. First, ensure that you are using 32-bit python and 32-bit pygame. Pygame only plays nice with 32-bit python, and you're opening a can of worms if you ignore that. The other thing to check is to make sure that all the modules are spelt the way that they are spelt on your system when you load in the dlls. (A common suspect is that Tkinter has an upper case module name and this might throw something off)

Comment: all 32 bit? I meant caps and the like. Check your dlls actually exist in the folder, and post some more code :)